# How to get from entered data into variable in react hook form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using react js with react hook form. I want to access selected value to do another condition. I want to know that how to access enterd forms value into js variable?

Comment: You'll have a better chance of receiving help if you post some actual code. Share what you have at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `watch` for it like below.

```
const { register, watch, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm();
const variable_name= watch("the_name_of_attribute"); // you can supply default value as second argument
```